# How do I list the current line in python PDB?

Tags: python, pdb

In the perl debugger, if you repeatedly list segments of code taking you away from the current line, you can return to the current line by entering the command `.` (dot).

I have not been able to find anything comparable using the python PDB module.  If I *list* myself away from the current line and want to view it again, it seems I have to either remember the line number that was currently executing (unlikely for me) or execute a statement (often undesirable).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 54):

Late but hopefully still helpful. Make the following alias:

```
alias ll u;;d;;l
```

Then whenever you type `ll`, pdb will list from the current position. It works by going up the stack and then down the stack, which resets 'l' to show from the current position. (This won't work if you are at the top of the stack trace.)

**Tip: Permanent alias**

To make the alias permanent, add the line into your `.pdbrc`-file in the user home directory (`~/.pdbrc`). This works with both pdb and ipdb.

Comment: Simple and worked for me. This should be marked as the answer!

Comment: This command is super handy. To save time, you can add this to a `.pdbrc` file so you don't have to enter it each time (described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands))

Comment: I couldn't do following to overwrite `alias l` =>  `alias l u;;d;;l` which enters into a loop

Answer (score 48):

In Python 3.2 and higher, you can use `list .` to reset the list location.

[Source: Python Bug tracker #4179](http://bugs.python.org/issue4179)

Comment: or in shortcut: `l.`

Answer (score 34):

This question is 7 years old now..

If there’s anyone who are curious about this problem, just use the dot

`(pdb) l .`

This now works.

Comment: `*** Error in argument: '.'
`

Answer (score 22):

Well, I don't think there's a command similar to `.` in perl debugger, but you can always find the current line using the `where` / `w` command. That will show you both the current (contextual) frame as well as the most recent frame, which I believe is where the debugger was triggered.

Comment: I didn't think of using "where' to get back.  It's less than ideal, but certainly better than nothing.  Thanks!